# What are the real life uses of role based authentication control in a database?

Tags: database, mongodb, roles

I was going through the [mongodb docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/) for Role Based Authentication Control. I have understood how it works, but I have a few questions.

How is it applied in real life scenarios? For example let's say I am running a blogging web app. How would I use Role Based Authentication Control to improve my app management?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Admin user is a super user, who can do any operation on any blogger accounts, their content. But, bloggers are limited only their content, their account

**Admin user:**

- A admin user will be able to see all the blog posts, even under draft stage.
- Admin user can hide or unhide any blogpost.
- Admin user will be able to delete or disable any account.
- Admin user will be able to take backup of any account blogposts.

**Blogger:**

- A blogger will be able to see only his/her blog posts.
- Blogger will be able to hide or unhide only his/her blogposts.
- Blogger will be able to delete or disable only his/her account.
- Blogger will be able to take backup of only his/her account blogposts.